# Using FindControl to get selected radio button via GroupName

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am creating groups of radio buttons dynamically. Each group has unique groupname. When user clicks submit button, I would like to get the value of the radio button that is selected in each group. I use the following code to generate :

```
                        RadioButton button = new RadioButton();

                        button.Text = btn.getName();
                        button.Checked = false;
                        button.GroupName = btn.getBtnGroupID();
                        Panel1.Controls.Add(button);
```

How do I use FindControl or alternatives to get the selected/checked button in each button group?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetRadioButtonValue(ControlCollection ctrlColl, string groupName)
{
  var selectedRbtn= controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.GroupName == groupName && rb.Checked);
  return selectedRbtn== null ? string.Empty :selectedRbtn.Attributes["Value"];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
RadioButton btnTest = (RadioButton)Panel1.FindControl("radioButtonId");

 if (btnTest.Checked == false) { 
 // do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    private List<RadioButton> rblist = new List<RadioButton>();
    private void GetCheckedRB(Panel pnl, string groupName)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in pnl.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)ctrl;                    
                if (rb.GroupName == groupName && rb.Checked)
                    rblist.Add(rb);
            }
        }
        //Put action here
        //MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", rblist.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray().ToString()));
    }
```